# Working with merged js and css in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I am following this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix.webpack('app.js')
    .styles([
        'bootstrap.min.css',
        'agency.css',
        'font-awesome.min.css',
        'bootstrap-social.css',
        'bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css',
        'select2.min.css',
        'icheck.css',
        'custom.css'
        ])
    .scripts([
        'jquery.easing.min.js',
        'jqBootstrapValidation.js',
        'agency.min.js',
        'moment.js',
        'bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
        'select2.min.js',
        'contact_me.js',
        'icheck.min.js',
        'ckeditor.js',
        'echo.js',
        'custom.js'
    ])
    .version(['css/all.css', 'js/all.js']);
 });
```

Here, I'm simply merging all css and js files into two files: all.css and all.js to minimise HTTP request(to improve performance)

Those two merged files, getting stored at

```
public/build/css/all-5ba9458ba4.css
public/build/js/all-1723826a20.js
```

And I'm including them into templates like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/all.css') }}">
<script src="{{ elixir('js/all.js') }}"></script>
```

The issue here is that those combined css and js i.e all.css and all.js getting stored inside of "build" directory.

So, I need to move other related dependencies (like fonts) inside that build directory.

So, what is the solution over here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Parth vora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elixir's `version` method allows you to set a path I believe

```
mix.version(['css/all.css', 'js/all.js'], 'public');
```

Then use

```
elixir('path/to/script.js', null) // note the null
```

In your case

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/all.css', null) }}">
<script src="{{ elixir('js/all.js', null) }}"></script>
```

Comment: no it didn't worked.
There is no such second parameter for mix.version()
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting

Comment: It's undocumented- See [here](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/src/tasks/recipes/version.js#L14). Looking at that code suggests you could also set `public.versioning.buildFolder` in your elixir config

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
mix.version(['style.css', 'script.js'], 'public');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting

Answer (score 0):

As per this documetation, I think there is no such option to provide custom path for version method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting